# Parsing The Response From Fetch Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I am not able to get the response string from the fetch method in my view render method.

The Collection Class Goes here.

```
 Collection = (function(){

    var Events;

    Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({


        url:function(){
           //alert(urlOptions);
         return this.urlParam;
           // alert('API call :'+urlOptions);
        },

        initialize: function(models, options){
            this.urlParam = options.urlParam || "";
        },

        parse: function( response ){
            var parsed = Jath.parse(
                [ '//notes', {

                } ], response );
            console.log(parsed);
            return parsed;

        }
        });

    return {
        newInstance : function(models,options) { return new Events(models,options); }
    };
})();


The View Goes Here 

    View = (function() {
  'use strict';

  var
    htmlTemplate = _.template( $('#eventGridTemplate' ).html() ), // See templatesSearch.jsp
    expanded = true, // By default the Events Grid extends to the bottom of the browser window.
    BackboneView, applyStyles;

  /**
   * Apply CSS specific to this view
   * Unfortunately, this View needs to modify its parent wrapper element.
   * Otherwise the layout will break when it's resized.  See templatesSearch.jsp.
   * @param {Object} $elmt
   * @param {Boolean} expand
   */
  applyStyles = function( $elmt, expand ) {

    var
      top   = '2px',
      left  = '2px',
      pos   = 'absolute',
      right = '2px';

    if ( expand ) {

      $elmt.css({
        "position" : pos,
        "top"      : top,
        "left"     : left,
        "right"    : right,
        "bottom"   : "2px"
      });

      $elmt.parent().css( 'bottom', '2px' );

    } else {

      $elmt.css({
        "position" : pos,
        "top"      : top,
        "left"     : left,
        "right"    : right,
        "bottom"   : "50%"
      });

      $elmt.parent().css( 'bottom', '50%' );
    }
  };

  // See 'http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor' for more info
  BackboneView = Backbone.View.extend({

    onAiringsBtn : function( event ) {

      // If the Events Grid container was expanded, contract it.
      // If it was contracted, expand it.
      expanded = expanded ? false : true;
      applyStyles( this.$('div'), expanded );
},

    initialize : function() {
  this.render();
    },

    render : function() {
      // this.$el is the jQuery version of this.el
      // Which is populated by options.el
      // Which is part of the options object passed into the constructor
      //alert('Start Date:' +$('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate'));
       var eventsCollection = Collection.newInstance([],{urlParam:'http://localhost:8080/adtglobal/2.0/api/events?startDate=2013-11-05T00:00:00-0400&endDate=2013-11-06T00:00:00-0400'});
       //console.log(eventsCollection.url());
        eventsCollection.fetch({
             success : function(eventsCollection , response){
                 console.log(eventsCollection.toJSON());
                 alert(eventsCollection.toJSON());
             }
                   });
        this.$el.html( htmlTemplate );
        applyStyles( this.$('div'), true );
    }
  });

  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Public API
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  return {
    newInstance : function(options) { return new BackboneView(options); }
  };

})();
```

I get The response as success and i see the xml in the browser console, but how do i parse it here ??

The response is here

```
<Events xmlns="urn:api:2.0">
<PageNavigation showing="45"></PageNavigation>
<Event id="400515625" href="400515625" source="SDR">
<OrgHierarchy>
<level id="56" typeId="100" title="Soccer" description="Sport" href="../sporthierarchy?levelId=56&levelTypeId=100"></level>
<level id="2902" typeId="101" title="UEFA" description="Confederation" href="../sporthierarchy?levelId=2902&levelTypeId=101" parentId="56" parentType="100"></level>
</OrgHierarchy>
<EventType id="1">Standard Event</EventType>
<League id="1860">UEFA > Polish Orange Ekstraklasa</League>
<EventTitleText>Ruch Chorzow vs. Zawisa Bydgoszcz</EventTitleText>
<CompetitionType id="1">Team vs Team</CompetitionType>
<EventCompetitors>
<Teams>
<HomeTeam id="73960" href="../teams/73960">Ruch Chorzow</HomeTeam>
<AwayTeam id="107278" href="../teams/107278">Zawisa Bydgoszcz</AwayTeam>
</Teams>
</EventCompetitors>
</Event>
</Events>
```

Comment: what does the 'parsed' value look like in your parse function?

Comment: Am not able to get any value there, The response is a xml which i can see in the console of the browser but not here. :-( I am very new to backbone probably i might have missed some basic stuff also :-(

Comment: can you post a sample of your server response here?

Comment: @YuruiRayZhang: I have posted the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it seems you are not using Jath correctly.

you need to define a template that matches your XML.

I have not used Jath before, but I will try to create a simple template for you:

```
//in your parse
var template = [ "//Events", {id: "@id", eventType: 'EventType'}];

return Jath.parse(template, response );
```

try this first and see if you have something in your collection.

it seems you have nested resources in your response, so you will have to complete the template.

or, if you don't have to use Jath, try something simpler: here's an example jsfiddle, you should be able to see the parsed JSON in the console.
http://jsfiddle.net/5j57T/

EDIT: xml to json code is from: http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json

**NOTE:** you need to parse that json again into an array of objects you need, in order to make your app work!

=====================

EDIT: another example (works better than the previous fiddle)
http://jsfiddle.net/5j57T/1/

uses a jquery library http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/

there's only one issue, since there's only one event in your events, it cannot be parsed to an array by default, you will have to do that manually. If, there's always only one event per response, you can do something like this:

```
parsed = [$.xml2json(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('event')[0])]
```

or you can just do

```
parsed = $.map(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('event'), function(eventXml) {
  return $.xml2json(eventXml);
});
```

working jsfidde: http://jsfiddle.net/5j57T/2/

==========================

**EDIT:**

I think by default, backbone is expecting a JSON response from the server. You will have to overwrite it's fetch() function so support XML. so in your collection definition, add this:

```
fetch: function (options) {
  options = options || {};
  options.dataType = "xml";
  return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```

here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5j57T/4/

Ignore the 'data' and 'type' options I passed to fetch(), and the url, all of that are just to make Ajax request work on jsfiddle. You shouldn't have those in your app.

In this demo, when the XML is returned, it's parsed into the collection correctly. You should be able to see your collection in the console.

======

If all of your backend services return XML only. I'd suggest overwrite the Backbone.sync function to make it work for other methods like save().

Comment: I want to see the raw response in the console, not worried about jath, i am planning to use the xmltojson itself but before i use that i should have the response in a variable right, which am failing to get.

Comment: see my edited answer for xmltojson. you need to return an array of objects in your parse function.

Comment: I have multiple events in the response, sorry for just posting only one, do i have to do the same thing for that also?

Comment: see the last part of the code piece, it works for multiple event tags.

Comment: i am not getting the eventXml at all how would i get that? That is the problem.

Comment: what is the value of 'response' is your parse function.

Comment: I am not able to print that :-( if i had got some value i would have figured it out by now :-( dont know whats wrong?

Comment: was your parse function being called at all?

Comment: No it is not, i checked by adding a console.log in the beginning of the function.

Comment: one sec. making another fiddle.

Comment: what's the response status of your ajax request. it seems it the fetch() method has decided that your ajax call failed.

Comment: it says 200 OK. I can see the url with that response.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. see the last part of edited answer.

Comment: Document is printed, and there is an error this.model is not a constructor.

Comment: which line is throwing that error?  BTW, since you are using a collection, you may want to define a model for that collection. I guess that's the reason of the error: it's trying to initialize models with the response but you don't have a model defined.

Comment: I tried overriding the backbone.sync, i got an error method is not defined.

Comment: You will have to override Backbone.sync only after backbone is loaded. if you have problem overriding that method, I'd suggest start a new post. And, also, try to define a model for your collection.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your gmail id so that we dont spam this forum.

Comment: uhm...i don't have an email address i can post in the internet. Well, if doesn't solve your question, try to update your question so people can get a better understanding of your problem. if this solves your question, but you encountered something else, i'd encourage you to open a new post.

Comment: I dont know where to override the sync method

Comment: then can you start a new post about that so other people can see it too?